# My update sql query keeps saying syntax error but I cant tell what it is

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2007

```
PreparedStatement stup = con.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE TrailerLocationMaster" +
        "SET Block = ?, Location = ?, Day = NOW(), SetTime = NOW(), Comment = ?" +
        "Where Trailer = ?;");

stup.setString(1, BlockName);
stup.setString(2, LocationName);
stup.setString(3, text);
stup.setString(4, TrailerName);
stup.addBatch();

stup.executeBatch();
```

Could someone explain why I get syntax error I followed the sql tutorial

Comment: don't forget to mark answers as accepted if it solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing spaces at the end of each line :

```
"UPDATE TrailerLocationMaster " +
                       //    ^ added space
"SET Block = ?, Location = ?, Day = NOW(), SetTime = NOW(), Comment = ? " +
                                                                  //   ^ added space
"Where Trailer = ?;");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query string is

```
UPDATE TrailerLocationMasterSET Block = ?, Location = ?, Day = NOW(), SetTime =  NOW(), Comment = ?Where Trailer = ?;
```

Note that there are no spaces between TrailerLocationMaster and SET and also between ? and WHERE.

Correct them and it should works